# Libreoffice writer autocorrect editing

Tags: libreoffice

Libreoffice autocorrect corrects lots of spelling mistakes as you type (no need to run the spell checker afterwards to catch these).

eg if you type I in English Libreoffice it is automatically changed to I.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this list list so if you want to disable eg capitalisation of I (if you are typing in another language) you can use:

Tools, Autocorrect, Autocorrect Options opens up a table of changes
left column is the typed value and the right column is the corrected value

Scroll down to i in the left column and use delete to remove this correction.